# How to retry R testthat test on API error?

Tags: r, api, travis-ci, testthat

Some tests rely on some external services (e.g. APIs). Sometimes, these external services will go down. This can cause tests to fail and (worse) continuous integration tools to fail.

Is there a way to instruct `testthat` tests and regular package examples re-run examples/tests more than once, ideally with the second attempt being 5 minutes after the first?

Comment: Are you automating having a test run? I understand one purpose of the set of tests is to detect (incompatible) changes in the API, but ... if you schedule it once and it fails, I would think that *that* would suggest to you that you should re-run the test (manually) to determine what is different. Lacking that, just write into your test code looping until it is either (1) good, or (2) an error that is not temporary. (Are you certain you'll know the difference between a temporary error and an API change?)

Comment: Run daily check of the API in Jenkins or other CI/Scheduling tool and delegate retry policy to that tool. Don't run code against real API on git push, it is absolutely pointless.

Comment: @r2evans the problem is if examples fail (they can't have loops in them and `Sys.sleep()` since CRAN don't like examples that run for longer than 5 seconds). Basically when someone contributes, if the tests fail, I go hunting around for what they did wrong, waste time, then only after some minutes (or longer), discover that the API was down for a brief time. This sounds easy to resolve when discussing here, but in practice, when there are 100s of changes any of which could cause failure, then finding the cause is not easy. So simply having tests 'try again in a minute' (like a human) is handy

Comment: @Bulat good idea, I will check this out. I am using Travis CI at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would write your tests in a way that they don't call API or database.

Instead you will mock API end points according to the specification and also write test for cases where API returns unexpected results or errors.

Here is an example of package that allows you to do so:

https://github.com/nealrichardson/httptest

If you are worried that your vendor might change API, talk to them and extract details on their API change management.

Ask them this:

> What is your change management process? 
>   How do you avoid introducing break changes to existing endpoints that people are using?

*(modified from this [post](https://medium.com/@schneidenbach/restful-api-best-practices-and-common-pitfalls-7a83ba3763b5))*

If you have to check that API is still the same, draw the line between API validation and testing of your code.

You will need two separate processes:

- Unit / Acceptance tests that are executed against the mocks of the API end points. Those run fast and are focused on the logic of your application.
- pipeline for regular validation of the API. If your code is already live, you are likely to find out of any breaking changes in API anyway. So this is highly redundant. In exceptional cases this can be useful, but only with a very bad vendor.

Comment: The thing is, I do not control the APIs, so I do want the tests to run (and fail if the API has changed in a way that breaks my code). I just don't want to be notified of test failures that are very temporary - i.e. due to very short server outages

Comment: Don't use API that does this `and fail if the API has changed in a way that breaks my code`

Comment: My code is a wrapper around a common API. Occasionally, that API may change. That's why I wrote the tests in the first place.

Comment: API integration should be based on the contract which changes in a way that does not break integrations that are already live. e.g. you provider should use versioning or extend it safely

Comment: Suppose we're talking about a google API over which I have no control or say about its structure and how it works. So I have tests to tell me if any of their API changes

Comment: So for example, lets say you have a version of your code that is `live` and API changes after you have done your testing. Change breaks your `live` code. What was the point of this test?

Comment: The tests run everyday by default, and after every push to git

Comment: With everyday check, your are not testing your code, you are just checking if the API contract is still the same. `testthat` is for testing your own code.

Comment: A daily check tells me if my code still works with the API, this has worked for me for the past 2 years. I just want to eliminate cases where tests fail due to an API being unavailable for a very short time (e.g. during server maintenance), which happens rarely but can be inconvenient when it happens

Comment: You need to draw the line between `testing that API did not change` and testing the logic of your code. `testthat` package is for the second part. you don't need testthat functionality to test that API is still the same.

Comment: a better alternative to httptest is the vcr package https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/vcr/ - its agnostic with respect to the http client, so you can change the client out in the future